# daterangepicker NotWorking in bootstrap model popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Daterangepicker not working in a bootstrap model popup
Here the working in HTML page jsfiddle link

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/150q2k7t/14/][1]
```

And I tried in Model It is not working

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/npb28m6z/3/][1]
```

Comment: According to me it happens due to some CSS problems while displaying it in modal.I read somewhere that in root element i.e in index.js we have to add few lines to make it work properly. Sorry, I don't have any idea right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle is missing the required dependencies (resources).

You should include them after bootstrap, in this specific order:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js
[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js)
[https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js)

In order to add them, you click `Resources` in the sidebar and then type the address and click the plus button `(+)`:

[image: The resources button]

[image: The sidebar with the resources]

Check it out on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5pytk1gh/

Answer (score 1):

`[http://jsfiddle.net/npb28m6z/3/][1]`

Just add to the Resources `moment.js` and `daterangepicker.js` dependencies.
Like you did it here - `[https://jsfiddle.net/150q2k7t/14/][1]`.

[image]
[image]